# Converting an nvarchar datatype to a datetime datatype created an out of bounds value

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I migrated MySQL database to SQL Server 2019.

All was Working fine with MySQL

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Converting an nvarchar datatype to a datetime datatype created
> an out of bounds value (SQL: insert into [roles] ([name],
> [guard_name], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (AgentControlleur,
> api, 2022-12-21 14:30:18.864, 2022-12-21 14:30:18.864))

I found this solution

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ModelFormat extends Model
{
   public function fromDateTime($value)
   {
      return Carbon::parse(parent::fromDateTime($value))->format('Y-d-m H:i:s.v');
   }
}
```

But it's too rough I have to modify a lot of things and after that it doesn't work for everything.

Is there a solution on the side of sql server like modifying the character encoding or something else?

Comment: Use an unambiguous format, such as `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnn)`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem: because my default language was French i changed it to English

I found this

**Solution**

You can change the default date format per user by selecting the default language for that user in

> SQL Management Studio > Security > Logins > {user properties} >
> Default language.

And you can see the date format for each language with

> EXEC sp_helplanguage

Comment: You need to cite your source when quoting other's work.